# Combinations of columns that meet a certain condition in R

Tags: r, combinations

I am fairly new to R and I would appreciate any help I get.
I have the following binary table:

```
example <- matrix(ncol=4,c(1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0))
colnames(example) <- c("c1","c2","c3","c4")
rownames(example) <- c("r1","r2","r3","r4","r5")
```

I would like to get all possible combinations of columns where all rows have a "1".
In this example, I would get the following output:

result = ((c1,c3),(c2,c1,c3),(c2,c1,c4),(c3,c1,c4),(c3,c1,c4,c2),(c4,c1))

Once again thank you for all the help.
Cheers

Comment: Hi Ronak, thanks for the heads up but I am also quite new to stackoverflow :) I added the R code to generate the binary table.

Comment: How exactly are column names generated? What do you mean by `combinations of columns where all rows have a "1".` ? Can you explain with the help of an example?

Comment: @RonakShah For example: 
column 1 (c1) has a "1" in all rows except row 3 (r3). To be selected it needs to be combined with another column where r3 has a "1". Hence, a combination set of c1,c3 is returned. My idea is to return all of these combinations where all rows would have a "1".  I hope this makes it easier.

Answer (score 2):

This needs some work, but thought I would throw this out there. I know others in SO can improve upon this (significantly, I might add). I would be very open to comments and improving this answer if I can.

First would get all combinations of column names, with varying lengths (vary from 1 to 4 columns), and put into a list.

```
lst <- do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(colnames(example)), combn, x = colnames(example), simplify = FALSE))
```

Second, would go through that list, and create matrices for those selected columns.

```
lst2 <- lapply(lst, function(x) matrix(example[,x], ncol = length(x)))
```

Third, would name the list based on the column names and remove the quotes.

```
names(lst2) <- gsub('[\"]', '', lst)
```

Fourth, would check each matrix in the list where (a) any column in a row has a 1, and (b) all rows meet criteria (a).

```
names(which(lapply(lst2, function(x) { all(apply(x, 1, function(y) any(y > 0))) } ) == TRUE))
```

**Output**

```
[1] "c(c1, c3)"         "c(c1, c4)"         "c(c1, c2, c3)"     "c(c1, c2, c4)"     "c(c1, c3, c4)"    
[6] "c(c1, c2, c3, c4)"
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks so much for the help. This solution works for the majority of the datasets that I have. However, it becomes memory intensive when increasing the table sizes. For example, if I have 150 columns and 5 rows and I limit the number of interacting columns to 5 (the maximum number of rows) then my laptop's memory explodes. Even submitting this to a server doesn't solve the issue. Is there anyway to make it less memory intensive? I was thinking that if we are able to generate the results without creating all the possible combinations a priori would solve this problem.

Comment: (cont) Basically it would mean get first combination, generate matrix, do the calculation and keep the result if it fits and then move on to the next combination. This way it would dump the memory used previously. I have been trying to see how I could do this but so far without success. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @user1879994 I understand what you mean - 150 columns is a lot of combinations. I'm sure there must be some better ways to approach this more efficiently; especially since larger combinations shouldn't be considered if small subset combinations do not meet criteria. There may be alternative packages to consider but this really gets outside my area and experience. I would recommend posting a separate question with this in mind. Maybe create a larger "example" matrix and indicate the problem of memory (and maybe speed) and need for efficiency.